# issue with dynamic update of onchange function

Tags: javascript, dynamic, onchange

I want to dynamically change any instances where 'form.submit();' appears in onchange functions for certain select elements to $('form').submit(); so that the submit event is triggered for the form itself.

Here's an example of such a select list where the onchange function needs to be updated:

```
<td class="form-field selectinput" align="left" valign="left" style="width: 90px;" title="Select status type">
        <select class="filterlist" name="cStatus" tabindex="5" style="width: 90px;" onchange="form.submit();">
          <option value="" title="[All]">[All]</option>
          <option value="A" title="Authorised">Authorised</option>
          <option value="C" selected="" title="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
          <option value="U" title="Declined">Declined</option>
          <option value="R" title="Requested">Requested</option>
          <option value="T" title="Taken">Taken</option>
          <option value="W" title="Withdrawn">Withdrawn</option>
        </select>
      </td>
```

I insert the following in the header section of the page to try and update the function :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
   $('select').each(function() {
     var txt = this.onchange ;
     alert(txt);
     var patt=/form.submit()/g;
     var result=patt.test(txt);
     if (result) {
        var txt =  txt.replace('form.submit()',""); 
        this.onchange = eval(txt);
     }
   });
});
```

});

The alert message comes up with:

> function onchange(event) {
>    form.submit();
>    }
>   Blockquote

and then the console log shows the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function onchange(event) {
>     form.submit();
>   } has no method 'replace'

I can actually get it to work with the following:

```
 this.onchange = function() { $('form').submit(); }
```

But there are some instances where the onchange has other code along with the form.submit(); such as:

```
form.submit();form.iYear.disabled=true;form.cGroupItem.disabled=true;
```

so i don't want to replace the whole function itself, but to cut out the 'form.submit();' and replace it with '$('form').submit();', so the above would then appear as:

```
$('form').submit();form.iYear.disabled=true;form.cGroupItem.disabled=true;
```

i've tried using toString() and eval() in various places but anytime i try to edit the string txt, i keep getting the object has no method error.

Any ideas??

Comment: For better and quicker answers, you should add a tag corresponding to the language you are using (Javascript?) by clicking on the edit link below your question.

Comment: onchange isn't a string; it's a function, which is why you're getting the "...has no method 'replace'" error.  It's coerced into a string when you use the alert.

Comment: steve, is there a way that the function can be manipulated as a string? can it be coerced into a string other than using alert ??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing your funky eval and replace just try this:

```
...
     if (result) {
        this.onchange = function(){}; //empty function
     }
...
```

Comment: thanks for the post, but i've updated the issue a bit more regarding the goal of preserving the code that appears alongside the form.submit() so if i use the above, i lose the other code.